# Allocate a contiguous block of memory

Tags: c, arrays

I try to work with a contiguous block of memory, more over I try to create an array who's dimensions are not known at compile time (before `C99`) so no `variable-length arrays` are involved here.

I came with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned int row, col,i, j, k;
    int l = 0;

    printf("Give the ROW: ");
    if ( scanf("%u",&row) != 1){
        printf("Error, scanf ROW\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Give the COL: ");
    if ( scanf("%u",&col) != 1){
        printf("Error, scanf COL\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * row * col); /* This doesn't compile with `-pedantic` */
    if(arr == NULL){
        printf("Error, malloc\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < row ; i++){
        for ( j = 0 ; j < col ; j++){
            arr[i * col + j] = l;
            l++;
        }
    }

    for (k = 0 ; k < (row * col) ; k++){
        printf("%d ",arr[k]);
    }

    free(arr);
}
```

Which give's me the following:

```
Give the ROW: 5
Give the COL: 5
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Now I have a Questions:

> Is this the right approach?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean with "the dimensions are not known at compile-time"? Their number or each length? For the first there is hardly a general sulution, for the latter best is to use standard C and a modern compiler which supports VLAs. If you are stuck with some rubbish ancient compiler, emulate the VLA with a single dimension array using the standard formula..

Comment: This is an OK approach.

Comment: @Olaf I mean you create the array after user Input I commented Out the part with scanf

Comment: 1. Yes it is. 2. What should `printf("%d\n", *(arr + 0));` print? `printf("%d\n", *(arr + 1));`?

Comment: `Why printf("%d\n", *(arr + 15)); prints 15 shouldn't be 14?` Because that's what you put there. What would you expect printing *(arr+0) to be? How about *(arr+1) ?

Comment: @n.m. `printf("%d\n", *(arr + 0));` is `0` Of course but i though that arr[15] will pribnt `14`

Comment: OK, what about *(arr+14) ? then *(arr+13) ? then...

Comment: Sorry about that I was thinking about somehting else. The second Question is OK `15` there. Sorry Guys. I removed that part, I probably need to sleep because I'm awake from more then 25 Hours

Comment: Better to post code review on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @chux You right sorry about that. If someone can move it please, do it. I'm not sure that I can do it myself.

Comment: You can delete here and post there.

Comment: _"Allocate a contiguous block of memory"_ `malloc` always allocates a contiguous block of memory, if it didn't pointer arithmetic would be a minefield

Comment: @Olaf Weren't VLA's made optional again in C11?

Comment: @chux To late, there are two answers now and I can not delete it anymore.

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem VLA was first specified in C99 and was required.  In C11 the specification is the same, but it is optional.

Comment: @Olaf you right about VLA's and probably I will never use an old Compiler or an older Standard then `C11`. More over with this approach I get another problems if I use `-pedantic`  =>> `warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wpedantic]` Here =>> `int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * row * col);`

Comment: @Michi That warning just means that you need to put all of the declarations at the top of the function. So `int *arr;` needs to be after `int l=0;`. Then the line with the `malloc` becomes `arr = malloc(...);`

Comment: @user3386109 You right, Thank you. I never used `-pedantic`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: That's why I added that part about "which supports ...". Do you know any compiler which supports C99, too does not provide VLAs for C11? Or any modern C11 compiler which does not support C99, too?

Comment: @Michi: Actually many coding standard prohibitmixing declarations and statements even iff they allow C99 or 11.

Comment: @Olaf If so, how would I change [this](http://ideone.com/RBehLF) program to compile with `-pedantic` ?

Comment: @Michi: `-std=c11` or `c99` would help.

Comment: @Olaf Don't know, but I can imagine MS's C compiler wouldn't support VLA's. They didn't fully support C99, in particular VLA's, so if they implemented C11, I'd be surprized if they did in fact add VLA support since then

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Don't use MSVC as a reference, IIRC I wrote about "modern (C11) compilers". Yes, MSVC is mot and has not been standard compliant since 17 years now. What is your point? MS does not set the standards (luckily), IEEE, ISO, and other international organisations do (or local for local standards of course).

Comment: @Olaf: Relax, You asked if I could think of a modern compiler that didn't support VLA's. I couldn't, but like it or not: MSVC is fairly widely used, especially by people who started to learn C on windows. So no, MSVC isn't what I'd call a standard compliant, modern compiler, but it's used enough to mention that VLA's might not work if you're using the MSVS toolchain

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Oh, I'm so well relaxed. I just can't stand if my comments are not read/understood entirely. MSVC does not support C11 nor C99, so it does not even match that criterion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a hidden error in this line:

```
arr[i * row + j] = k;
```

The correct index calculation is

```
arr[i * col + j] = k;
```

The reason that you don't notice that problem is that `row` and `col` have the same value in the code. If, for example, you set `row` to 6 and `col` to 3, the error will be obvious. You will allocate space for 18 ints, but when `i` is 5 and `j` is 2, the code will try to access location `[5*6 + 2]` which is off the end of the array, and will result in undefined behavior.

Here's how the address calculation works. The drawing below shows how a 2D array (row=6 and col=3) is actually laid out in memory. Note that the number of items on each row is equal to the number of columns in the array. So the starting index for each row is a multiple of the number of columns. In this example, since the number of columns is 3, the rows start at indexes 0,3,6,9,... So given an element at index `[i][j]` in the 2D array, the index in the 1D array is `i*col + j`.

[image]

Comment: To add to this, it's because the number of elements in each row is the number of columns... so to find the offset for a given row, you need to multiply the row index `i` by the size of a row, which is `col`.

Comment: @Dmitri "the size of a row, which is col" can be confusing. as _size_ often implies the _byte size_.  Perhaps "multiply the row index `i` by the column count, which is `col`" for greater clarity.

Comment: @chux I probably should have said "number of elements" or "size in elements" of a row... but I thought it was clear enough from the preceding statement.

Comment: @dimitri and @ chux Thanks, I'll add a drawing and an explanation of how the addressing works.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for the Graphics

Answer (score 1):

The approach is okay. And the dimensions are known at compile time.

The reason for getting 15 is that `arr` it represents the base address so when you add 15 to `arr` it will give you the address of block containing 15 and later on de-referencing you will get 15.

Comment: `arr[i * row + j]` is not OK.

Comment: `And the dimensions are known at compile time` No are not, I shared the Whole code and there is a commented part where `scanf` is present. This line `row = 5, col = 5;` is there because I was trying to explain the User Input.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the number of *dimensions* ahead of time (1, 2, 3, or more dimensions), then this is the *only* approach you have available.  If you know the number of dimensions, but not their values, and you don't have VLAs available, again, this is the only approach you have available.

Because I am *bored out of my freaking skull* from writing documentation, I womped up this quick and dirty prototype to demonstrate how you can map a 1D array onto arrays of different numbers of dimensions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

/**
 * Compute the offset into a 1D array based on a set of dimensions
 * and indices, and return the element at that offset.  You must pass
 * at least as many indices as number of dimensions; any extra indices
 * will not be processed.  
 *
 * Inputs:
 *    a       -- 1D array of data
 *    ndims   -- number of dimensions to map array onto
 *    dims    -- dimension sizes
 *    ...     -- index values
 *
 * Outputs: none
 *
 * Returns: value at desired index
 */
int access( const int * restrict a, size_t ndims, const size_t * restrict dims, ... )
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start( ap, dims );  point to first index value in argument list

  size_t idx = 0;

  /**
   * To find the right index for a given number of dimensions, 
   * we need to compute
   *
   *  d0 x d1:           i * d1 + j             
   *  d0 x d1 x d2:      i * d1 * d2 + j * d1 + k
   *  d0 x d1 x d2 x d3: i * d1 * d2 * d3 + j * d1 * d2 + k * d1 + l
   *
   * The loop below computes these as
   *
   *    i * d1 + j
   *    (i * d2 + j) * d1 + k
   *    (((i * d3 + j) * d2) + k) * d1 + l
   *
   * etc.
   */
  for ( size_t i = 1; i < ndims; i++ )
  {
    idx += va_arg( ap, size_t ); // get next index argument and advance ap
    idx *= dims[i];
  }
  idx += va_arg( ap, size_t );
  va_end( ap );
  return a[idx];
}

int main( void )
{
  int test[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  size_t dims2x5[] = {2, 5};       // for mapping test onto a 2x5 array
  size_t dims3x3[] = {3, 3};       // for mapping test onto a 3x3 array
  size_t dims2x2x2[] = {2, 2, 2};  // for mapping test onto a 2x2x2 array

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < dims2x5[0]; i++ )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < dims2x5[1]; j++ )
      printf( "test[%zu][%zu] = %d\n", i, j, access( test, 2, dims2x5, i, j ) );

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < dims3x3[0]; i++ )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < dims3x3[1]; j++ )
      printf( "test[%zu][%zu] = %d\n", i, j, access( test, 2, dims3x3, i, j ) );

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < dims2x2x2[0]; i++ )
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < dims2x2x2[1]; j++ )
      for ( size_t k = 0; k < dims2x2x2[2]; k++ )
        printf( "test[%zu][%zu][%zu] = %d\n", i, j, k, access( test, 3, dims2x2x2, i, j, k ));

  return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
test[0][0] = 0
test[0][1] = 1
test[0][2] = 2
test[0][3] = 3
test[0][4] = 4
test[1][0] = 5
test[1][1] = 6
test[1][2] = 7
test[1][3] = 8
test[1][4] = 9

test[0][0] = 0
test[0][1] = 1
test[0][2] = 2
test[1][0] = 3
test[1][1] = 4
test[1][2] = 5
test[2][0] = 6
test[2][1] = 7
test[2][2] = 8

test[0][0][0] = 0
test[0][0][1] = 1
test[0][1][0] = 2
test[0][1][1] = 3
test[1][0][0] = 4
test[1][0][1] = 5
test[1][1][0] = 6
test[1][1][1] = 7
```

This isn't *pretty* - `access( a, 3, dims2x2x2, i, j, k )` doesn't exactly read as easily as `a[i][j][k]`.  With some additional levels of abstraction you could clean that up a bit, but it's always going to feel a bit awkward.  And naturally you sacrifice some performance.  But, if you need to be able to map a 1D array onto an arbitary-sized N-dimensional array where you don't even know the number of dimensions ahead of time, this is a possible solution.